# Showing Two (Or More) Random Variables are Identically Distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

In my probability course I'm taking at uni we have come across the situation where we want to show two or more independent random variables $X_i$ for i = 1,2,... are identically distributed. What we did to 'show' this is reason thus: the mean and the variance for $X_i$ was computed and we arrived at the result that they had the same mean and variance independent of the index. Since they all had the same statistics, we concluded that they are i.i.d (then went on to use CLT).

I see some problems with this.

Is it not possible that two distributions have the same mean and variance but are not identically distributed? I.e. they have the same mean and variance, but not the same other statistic? I find it hard to believe that you can describe all random variables by just the mean and variance. I have no example but it seems feasible to me that one could construct a pair of such random variables as a counterexample. If this is true, then we have not really 'shown' anything, we just have motivated that they are likely to be identically distributed but have not proven anything rigorously. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, there are many different distributions with same mean and variance. There are even distinct distributions with all moments equal. Perhaps you know more about your random variables? For example they're normal? There are some known distributions that are uniquelly described by mean and variance.

Comment: @DominikKutek does that mean that if we know a distribution belongs to a certain family (normal, binomial, etc.) then the above approach is rigorous?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But without further assumptions on distribution, mean and variance isn't enough to characterise it.